# How to suppress missing field warnings for record fields isomorphic to void?

Tags: haskell, record, ghc

Lets say I have a datatype like the following:

```
data File' key generated value = File
{
  id :: key Int,
  md5Hash :: generated Text,
  contents :: value Text,
  description :: value Text
  .
  .
}
```

then I can then have things like this:

```
type FileCreate = File' (Const Void) (Const Void) Identity
type FileUpdate = File' Identity (Const Void) Maybe
type FileLookup = File' Identity (Const Void) (Const Void)
type File = File' Identity Identity Identity
```

But here's the annoying thing.

Lets say I want to do a file lookup, so I do it like so:

```
FileLookup { id = Identity 1234 }
```

Then I'm going to get warnings about unassigned record fields. I want to keep these warnings on, because if I do:

```
FileCreate { description = Identity "This file hasn't had 'contents' assigned so this should be an error" }
```

then this is an error, and I want the warning to alert me about this. But in the case of `FileLookup`, the other fields are `Const Void`. They have no valid values anyway, as `Const Void` is newtyped to `Void`.

Here my options seem to be:

1. Make a function `fileCreate :: Text -> Text -> FileCreate`, `fileUpdate :: Int -> Text -> Text -> FileUpdate`,  `fileKey :: Int -> FileLookup` etc, but this seems boilerplatey and I lose the nice record syntax.
2. I could use the GHC extension ['record patterns'](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html#record-pattern-synonyms) to create separate patterns similarly as point 1, but that's still a lot of boilerplate, particularly as I'll have to create 3 or 4 specialised record pattern synonyms for EVERY new datatype I define.

In my actual problem I'm likely to have lots of these "File" like datatypes but probably only around 5 patterns (insert, update, lookup etc). So happy to do some boilerplate for these patterns as long as I don't have to repeat it for every new datatype.

Happy to use Generics if it helps. Would like to avoid Template Haskell if possible but if it's the only way I guess I'll deal. But ideally I'd like something like

```
{-# PRAGMA DontWarnIfThisParticularTypeOrANewtypeOfThisParticularTypeIsNotInitialisedInARecord #-}
data MyConstVoid a -- no constructors
```

and just use `MyConstVoid` instead of `Const Void` (which I'm happy to do). I just can't find a warning suppressor like that.

Comment: Are you sure you want `Const Void`? That makes `FileCreate, FileUpdate, FileLookup` morally isomorphic to `Void`. Sure, you can fill the void fields with bottoms, but... why? Storing bottoms in a data structure is perhaps something to be avoided. I'd use `Const ()` instead.

Comment: I’m happy with ‘Const ()’. I just want to avoid the boilerplate of filling in all the () fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why I don't think this is a great design

The trouble is those fields **are** uninitialised (which mean they contain bottom). And you're relying on them containing bottom, since `Const Void` has no non-bottom inhabitants. You want GHC to understand your intentions so that it can warn about *some* uninitialised fields but not others.

I suppose I can see why "this field can't be initialised (except to bottom)" might be expected to suppress a warning about not initialising the field. The trouble is that doesn't actually fit the idioms around how `Void` is used.

In particular, your type says that `getConst . value` applied to a `FileLookup` is *supposed* to produce a value of type `Void`. We've all agreed that once you have a `Void`, you can use [`absurd :: Void -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Void.html#v:absurd) to convert it to any type you like. For example, I was able to write this program using your suggested types:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Void
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative

data File' key generated value = File {
  id' :: key Int,
  md5Hash :: generated Text,
  contents :: value Text,
  description :: value Text
}


type FileCreate = File' (Const Void) (Const Void) Identity
type FileUpdate = File' Identity (Const Void) Maybe
type FileLookup = File' Identity (Const Void) (Const Void)
type File = File' Identity Identity Identity


wat :: FileLookup -> anything
wat = absurd . getConst . contents

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let q :: [Maybe (Either () [Double])]
      q = wat $ File { id' = 123 }
  print q
```

The *only* compile-time problem this has is the warning you want to disable:

```
Main.hs:26:17: warning: [-Wmissing-fields]
    • Fields of ‘File’ not initialised:
        md5Hash :: Const Void Text
        contents :: Const Void Text
        description :: Const Void Text
```

Calling `contents` on a `FileLookup` is perfectly fine by the type-checker, so long as we can handle the resulting `Const Void` (which is easy to do, since we have `absurd`). So if your desired functionality existed, this program would compile warning-free and then blow up at runtime. with `Main: Main.hs:26:17-34: Missing field in record construction contents`.

The way `Void` is expected to be used is more commonly to mark cases of a **sum** type that cannot happen. For example `Either Void b` is a type that can only contain values of the form `Right (_ :: b)`; to have constructed a `Left Void` we would have first needed a value of type `Void` to apply `Left` to.<sup>2</sup> Then `either absurd` is a way to handle such `Either Void b` values, relying on the assumption that `either` will never take its `Left` branch (and thus will never actually apply `absurd` to anything) because no such value will ever exist, **and checking** that this case is "impossible" by requiring it to have type `Void` (unlike handling an "impossible" case with something like `error "will never happen"`, which will happily convert into a runtime bug when the types change so that the impossible case is now possible).

It's less common to see it in a purely *product* type, like yours, since that would indicate that that `FileCreate` (etc) values will never exist, rather than indicating that certain of their fields will never be used.

Thus I think it unlikely that there would be any specific support your idiom built into the compiler, in the form of treating the "uninitialised field" warning differently based on the type of the field. `Void` simply isn't designed to be used that way.

In fact, the fact that it's `Void` rather than any other specific type isn't really doing anything. The only use you're getting out of it is that if someone accidentally tries to fill in the `contents` of a `FileLookup` they will almost certainly get a type error telling them about the mistake, since `Const Void` won't match the type that would normally go in the `contents` field (and the same thing if anyone tries to read such a field). But `Const ()` isn't going to match their expected type either; nor would `Const MyUnexportedType`, nor even something arbitrary and dumb like `Const [Maybe (Either () [Double])]`. You aren't really getting any use out of the fact that `Void` is uninhabited by simply leaving the field uninitialised; you could leave a field of any other unlikely-to-be-useful type uninitialised and get almost exactly the same type safety.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course `Left undefined` works perfectly well to construct a value of `Either Void b` that uses the `Left` constructor. We basically trust that there is a "gentlemen's agreement" not to do things like that though; it's generally hard to *accidentally* bypass the type checker in that way, and `Void` is specifically intended to support the style of programming where we try to ensure everything is total and invariants are checked by the compiler.

---

#### So what do I think you *should* do?

Maybe it's just the simplified example you've given here, but I also don't really see that you're getting "nice" syntax out of this pattern. `FileLookup { id = 123 }` *looks* nice, but it doesn't actually work that way; `FileLookup` is a **type**; record creation syntax is used with a **constructor**. So you actually have to use `File { id = 123 }`; nothing says that it's a lookup. A `FileDelete` would presumably also only need an `id` and thus would also look like `File { id = 123 }`.

Furthermore the `{ id = 123 }` bit only looks nice because there's a `Num` instance for `Identity`. There's an `IsString` instance too, so if you're using `OverloadedStrings` your `Text` fields also probably look nice. But anything past that will make you start writing things like `{ flag = Identity True }`, and you'll still have to deal with adding and removing `Identity` wrappers if you want these fields to connect to anything that deals in plain `Int` and `Text` values, even if you can have invisible `Identity` wrappers with literals in your source code.

Really the pattern synonym version (where the unused fields are based on `()` rather than `Void`) would be *much* nicer to use in practice. And creating a pattern synonym per operation per data type isn't *much* more boilerplate than creating a type synonym per operation per data type. Here's a quick example I knocked up:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, OverloadedStrings, DuplicateRecordFields #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Text

-- same as before
data File' key generated value = File {
  id' :: key Int,
  md5Hash :: generated Text,
  contents :: value Text,
  description :: value Text
}

-- GHC couldn't figure out the constraints with a plain deriving clause on the
-- data type; this isn't important, it's just so I could demo usage in main
deriving instance (Show (key Int), Show (generated Text), Show (value Text))
  => Show (File' key generated value)

-- Unnecessary, but a decent amount of boilerplate reduction, and more easily
-- conveys the "disallowed" sense.
type X = Const ()
pattern X = Const ()

-- Note that here the id' value is a real Int, not an Identity Int. The
-- pattern can transparently apply/remove the Identity wrapper for us.
-- It's entirely up to you whether you do that, but I sure would.
-- (Using the real File constructor makes the Identity visible, of course)
pattern FileLookup :: Int -> File' Identity X X
pattern FileLookup { id' } = File (Identity id') X X X

-- Note that the type signatures for the pattern synonyms are optional
-- if you're averse to boilerplate; I've included them here for clarity
pattern FileUpdate :: Int -> Maybe Text -> Maybe Text -> File' Identity X Maybe
pattern FileUpdate { id', contents, description } = File (Identity id') X contents description

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ FileLookup { id' = 123 }
  print $ FileUpdate { id' = 123, contents = Just "foo", description = Nothing }
```

Here's what this prints, so you can see it's filled in the

```
File {id' = Identity 123, md5Hash = Const (), contents = Const (), description = Const ()}
File {id' = Identity 123, md5Hash = Const (), contents = Just "foo", description = Nothing}
```

And if you leave a field out, like `FileUpdate { id' = 123, contents = Just "foo" }`, then you of course get an uninitialised fields warning:

```
Main.hs:36:11: warning: [-Wmissing-fields]
    • Fields of ‘FileUpdate’ not initialised:
        description :: Maybe Text
```

##### One note:

A big enough issue that I didn't want to bury it in comments in the code example: pattern synonyms with record syntax of course define their own fields and selector functions. So I had to turn on [`DuplicateRecordFields`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/duplicate_record_fields.html) to allow this, and if you try to use `id'` as a selector you'll almost certainly get an ambiguity error.

What I would probably really do is define the pattern synonyms in a separate module with `DuplicateRecordFields` and [`NoFieldSelectors`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/field_selectors.html#extension-FieldSelectors), and then use [`DisambiguateRecordFields`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/disambiguate_record_fields.html) at the usage sites. Then you would only have to worry about qualifying them if you use record *update* syntax (not pattern matching or record creation) in a module where you both the real type and a pattern synonym (or two pattern synonyms) in scope.

Alternatively it might be nice to `NoFieldSelectors` the real type as well, and only ever use explicit patterns. The pattern synonyms I've defined don't merely not use the unused fields, they actually *enforce* that the unused fields are `Const ()`. If you consume these records (presumably in a module that's actually carrying the operations out) by writing patterns using `File` directly (leaving the unused fields unmatched) or calling the field selector functions, then someone could initialise *all* fields and use that record with any operation, with no type safety. But if the `FileLookup` etc patterns are used at the *use* sites as well as the creation sites, then that would be caught as an error. (Although if everything ends up *completely* separated, there's not much point in having a single record; separate data types for each pattern synonym would be simpler. Presumably there is *some* level where you handle these things generically without caring what kind of operation is in them)

Comment: Any particular reason to suggest `Const ()` instead of `Proxy`?

Comment: Thanks' for your detailed reply @ben! I'm going to go with the pattern synonym like you suggest for the moment, and use `()` instead of `Void`. Maybe one day I can make a GHC proposal and extension that adds this behaviour (although it's not trivial to do so in a way that doesn't suppress warnings for existing code).

Comment: Also @ben well spotted on the lack of `Identity` in my question, that was an unintentional omission, I do realise I'd need to put something like that in.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yeah, that'd work too. I was just replacing `Void` with `()` in the OP's idea, but replacing `Const ()` with `Proxy` is probably better (and feels "quiet" enough to maybe not bother with the `X` synonyms). I think if I was *really* doing this I'd make my own empty (but not uninhabited) type to be more explicit, and make it clearer in `Show` output.

Comment: @Clinton Maybe you could get such a proposal accepted. The only reason I can see against it is that it would be odd for GHC to support this usage of `Void` (nobody is supposed to *care* whether a `Void`-isomorphic field is allowed to be uninitialised, because no object containing a `Void`-isomorphic field is supposed to ever exist). I don't know whether that objection would be enough for the GHC maintainers to actively want this functionality *not* to exist, but I can't imagine many of them jumping to implement it.

Comment: @Ben I've accepted your suggestion about `Void`, I've gone with `()` now. It still could be defaulted although I would think that any proposal should probably only apply to new data types designed specifically for this defaulting purpose, but one could define `newtype DefaultingUnit = DefaultingUnit ()`

Comment: @Clinton Yes, it would definitely be handy to have a way of specifying a default for fields that aren't set in record creation syntax (instead of leaving them as bottom). I think the usual pattern is to have a default record as a separate definition and use record update syntax to fill in specific fields, but that requires you to have a good default for *everything* (or bad defaults and get no warnings if you don't replace them).